Issue installing Key-mon on Ubuntu 24.04
I am having a problem running Key-mon on Ubuntu 24.04. I have installed Python 3 and what I think are all dependencies. When trying to run Key-mon, I get the following error:
Error: Missing xlib, run sudo apt-get install python3-xlib
However, if I try installing python3-xlib, I get the following message, confirming that I did indeed install it:
python3-xlib is already the newest version (0.33-2).
I am at a loss knowing what I am missing here. Any help would be welcome.

python3 would already have been installed on the system - did you install an additional version of it, and if so, how?
